# FullCalendar Dragging Multiple Events

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I would like to select (via check box) multiple events on the FullCalendar and then move all selected events together to a different date/time.

I have gotten as far as placing check boxes inside events. But not sure how to go further.

Note that I know about using the id variable which is used for recurring events. I would like to avoid using the id variable if possible and go down the check box route of selecting and moving multiple events.

Can someone help me get started on moving the selected events?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

I've added a non-standard field to the event object called selected which defaults to 0. When the event's checkbox is checked, the selected variable for that event is set to 1.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wanting to do this, here is how I did it:

1. In the `eventClick` method check to see if the checkbox inside the event is checked, if so, set your non-standard event property (selected) to 1 or true.
2. In the `eventDrop` method check to see which events have the selected property set to 1 or true and update those events' start and end dates/times.
3. Don't forget to use `$('calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);` to update the event after changing properties inside `eventDrop`
4. Lastly in `eventRender` which I used to place the checkboxes inside the event elements, make sure that is the events's selected property is 1 or true, the respective checkbox is checked.

That should do it.